# How do you pass a reference when using a typename as a function argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have some weird problem with templates. When trying to pass a parameterised iterator it complains that no function can be found. The code snippet is here, forget about the functionality, it's using the reference to the templatized iterator what interests me

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print_list_element(typename std::list<T>::iterator& it){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::list<int> theList;
    theList.push_back(1);

    std::list<int>::iterator it = theList.begin();
    print_list_element(it);

    return 0;
}
```

If you try to compile this with g++ v4.3.2 it complains with a message saying that:

```
main.cpp:14: error: no matching function for call to 'print_list_element(std::_List_iterator<int>&)'
```

Is there something wrong with the code I wrote or is that g++ needs more information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

g++ can't figure out which template overload of `print_list_element` it should use. If you explicitly specify the template parameter it works:

```
print_list_element<int>(it);
```

Answer (score 5):

A better way is to write the function like this:

```
template<typename Iter>
void print_element(Iter it){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

This will now work for any type of iterator, not just `std::list<T>::iterator`. Also, the template type will be deduced correctly from the argument.

I realize that it was a contrived example, but almost always you probably didnt want to pass in `list<T>::iterator` to a function anyways. At worst, at least template on ListType so that your code would work with lists with custom allocators.

Comment: +1. This will even work for plain arrays. If for some reason you really want it to work *only* for std::list<T>, look up Boost's enable_if<> template.

Answer (score 4):

That is illegal because std::list< T >::iterator is not what the standard calls a proper deduced context

Comment: I think the appropriate part of the '03 standard is: 14.8.2.4/4.  Also the standard says that this is a "non-deduced context", rather than your wording above.

Answer (score 4):

The other responses are correct, but for completeness I'll just add that, by design, C++ can only deduce template arguments automatically *in certain cases*, and this isn't one of them.

When you think about it, you'll realise that automatic deduction in this case would lead to an undesirable situation.  `std::list<T>::iterator` is not a real type, it's just a `typedef` alias for a real type (e.g. it might be `T*`) to which it is immediately translated, so the compiler would have to build some sort of "reverse index" in order to map `T*` back to `std::list<T>::iterator` for automatic deduction of `T` to work here.  But this mapping would break as soon as another class template was created that had a type member called `iterator` that was `typedef`ed to `T*` -- then the compiler would have two choices of what to translate `T*` to, and no way to choose between them.  Clearly, any automatic deduction policy that breaks when *an unrelated class adds a particular `typedef` type member* is much too fragile to work.